# Flex-box stack last item in row below the rest when on mobile width

Tags: html, css

I have a flex-box row which contains three `div` containers. I'd like the last `div` container to stack below the other containers when a certain width is reached (mobile).

Want to accomplish this using flex-box:
[image: Flex-box image example]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cart_item">
    <div class="cart_image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/01RSUK6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cart_item_details">
        <div class="item_title">
            <p>Item Title: Cute Fox</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart_item_price">
        <div class="price"> Price: $8.99</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
  max-width: 100%  
}

.cart_item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    padding: 15px;
}

.cart_image {
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.cart_item_details {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #0a0918;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

.cart_item_price {
    text-align: right;
}
```

I haven't been able achieve the desired result.

Here's a Fiddle:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dheb9sfa/)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rules:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cart_item {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .cart_item_price {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! However, a quick question for you, is there any way to have `div` container #3 stack below, and align with `div` container #2? Or would I need to add a fourth `div` container in mobile to mimic the width of `div` container #1 (the image)?

Comment: If your div #1 is fixed width you can just apply ```margin-left: 50px;``` to your div #3